# Picturebox dice roll (making the pictures scroll to look like it's dice rolling)?

Tags: vb.net

I have a timer which scrolls through the numbers 1-6 and lands on a random one. Problem is I have a picturebox which I need to do the same. I have the dice images but I can't figure out how to scroll all the dice images to match the code I have below. I want to have both of them running so they match up. I'm totally stuck!!

```
 Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        m = m + 10
        If m < 1000 Then
            n = Int(1 + Rnd() * 6)
            LblDice.Text = n

        Else
            Timer1.Enabled = False
            m = 0
        End If


    End Sub

    Private Sub RollDiceBtn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles RollDiceBtn.Click
        Timer1.Enabled = True

        DisplayDie(die1PictureBox)

    End Sub
```

Comment: Please don't edit away your question, part of the point is for others to read and learn too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is the best solution but you can put the "rolling images" in an imageList with the order that you want. Then with a counter inside the TimerTick you can shpw the next image in the imageList.

I found this code in my emails:

```
 Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    If ticks < 11 Then 'I got 11 images
        PictureBox1.BackgroundImage = ImageList1.Images(ticks)
        ticks += 1
    Else
        ticks = 0
        PictureBox1.BackgroundImage = ImageList1.Images(ticks)
        ticks += 1
    End If
End Sub
```

After comments:
You add an imageList to your Form.You are setting the properties for your images in imageList(size, depth).In your imageList you add the 6 images for your dice. 
Then you add this code:

```
 Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    m = m + 1 
    If m < 10 Then 'How many ticks (rolls) do you like
        n = Int(1 + Rnd() * 6)
        Label1.Text = n 'The labels is showing your random number (dice number)
        PictureBox1.Image = ImageList1.Images(n - 1) 'This is showing the dice image to the pictureBox:the same as the number
        'I use n-1 because imageList is zero based.
        'Important: my images are in the right order 1,2,3,4,5,6 in the imageList
    Else
        Timer1.Enabled = False
        m = 0
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Timer1.Enabled = True
End Sub
```

Comment: ok.. so if I put that code in.. how do I put the 6 different dice in an imagelist? Right now to display the picture I'm using                                              diePicture.Image = Image.FromFile( _
           Directory.GetCurrentDirectory & "/Images/die" & _
           face & ".png")                                              And how do I make sure the right picture shows up when the timer stops at a certain number? Thanks

Comment: Your random number is not right. Every time that you starting the program is the same sequence, but this is a different question, not answering here.